# Using properties of a class inside a trait

Tags: php, symfony, traits

I just came across an unexpected behavior regarding traits.

In a Symfony 6.2 project I use a trait inside a Controller. When calling $this->getUser() or $this->isGranted() it will actually perform correctly and fetch the user or the voter result, just like if it was executed inside the Controller class.

Obviously the code of the trait is executed in the context of the Controller class, so the attributes / methods of the Controller are available inside the trait in this scenario.

Is this intended behavior or just a side effect which I should not rely on?

Pseudo Code:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractController
{
    use SomeTrait;

    #[Route('/api/some-route', methods:['GET'])]
    public function doSomething(){
        // code
        $this->callTraitMethod();
        // code
    }
}

trait SomeTrait
{
    public function callTraitMethod()
    {
        // code
        $this->getUser(); // works correctly !
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for future reference you might consider calling class instance data properties and not attributes.  Attributes have a very distinct definition.  I suppose you might be able to access the attributes from a trait but that would be unusual.  I only mentioned it because it makes for a somewhat confusing title.

Comment: Yeah, those terms are used interchangeably on the web. Attributes, Properties, fields... but I agree with you.

Comment: Now reading all the comments etc., and thinking, I need to ask: Are you concerned about the use of class _properties_ or _methods_ in a trait? In the title I read _properties_ but in the code I only read _methods_. What is/was your intention? @tweekz

Comment: @hakre Originally the title read "using attributes of a class" and not properties.  The OP edited things after my original comment.  Hence the confusion.  I should probably delete my first comment but then it would just make the subsequent comments confusing.

Comment: Both. To me it seems like bad coding style to reference properties and/or methods that are not defined in the trait.

Comment: @tweekz: Ah, good to know. Because I was under the impression you were running into problems with properties specifically. And the code-style-rule you have for yourself looks sane to me for traits, but mind if you consider it strictly, you can't use traits for template code of internal implementations. You perhaps don't do, and henceforth such a rule naturally can help a lot. IMHO a good code-style should guide against the use of traits in general and have appropriate exceptions without limiting them.

Comment: I fully agree that it should be avoided.  But that is not what you asked.  There are actually quite a few folks who thing that traits themselves are bad coding styles.  I'm not one of them but I do think their use should be restricted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coming from Java and there pretty much everything is neatly defined (at least indirectly). So it was kind of a culture shock that my code still worked after refactoring it into a Trait without passing the classes properties explicitly.

Comment: So perhaps the little that could be added is, that traits were added to the PHP language because it has single inheritance. So it is possible to share more code between classes, without the need to change to multiple inheritance (runs into the diamond problem). Not sure if traits exist in Java at all.

Comment: @hakre That's exactly what I thought it was made for. I didn't expect it to get "merged" though. I can only imagine how much unintended behavior that can lead up to in more complicated code.

Comment: See last sentence in my answer^^. And thinking: Why don't you do composition instead? Or was it like: Hmm, what does this IDE refactoring could mean ... ?

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously the code of the trait is executed in the context of the Controller class, so the attributes / methods of the Controller are available inside the trait in this scenario.
>
> Is this intended behavior or just a side effect which I should not rely on?

This is **intended behavior** and *not* a side effect.

Use (pun intended) the syntax as a mnemonic, *the class **uses** the trait*. The class by *use* also controls overrides.

So the trait effectively is template code only.

You *could* follow the understanding of Barbara Liskov that an abstract (super)class should not contain protected properties at all and transpose that onto traits. While this does not fit 1:1, you *could* design to only use methods within the traits's code and never properties (both not defining nor accessing), to design better for abstraction while you write template code.

*"Traits are copy and paste at runtime."* (I don't remember where I heard it first, so if anyone remembers, leave a comment.)

---

You then clarified in a comment:

> I guess coding relying on implementations of a class that is using this trait is not a good practise. Or is it actually intended to be used like that?

As long as you rely on the abstract class interface, this is common practice I'd say and done day-to-day in the millions all around the world. You may wanna question if traits are good practice and if you want to rely on the templates defined therein, then it perhaps makes more sense, but the trait is never leading, and a class using the wrong trait is a broken class, not a trait relying on implementations of a class. A trait just is.

You can use it however it suits you.