# What really are scalar and compound data types in PHP?

Tags: php, object, types, scalar, complex-data-types

I know that an array and an object are composites, because more than one value can be stored in them, while scalars are "primitive" data, i.e. a single value.

But are compound types really objects?

For example, as in Java, almost everything is an object, an `Array`, an instantiation of a `class`, a `Map` etc., but in PHP, does something similar happen? `Array`, `ArrayObject`, `Map`, etc. Do they inherit from Object?

Or are they just "special" objects?

Where can I find more information about this?

Thank you :)

Comment: _Do they inherit from Object?_ There is no such single most highest parent class in PHP. Java is OOP completely(although not totally pure, but still). PHP involves both procedural and OOP style. I presume PHP wasn't meant to be in an OOP style by default during it's inception by design.

Comment: For what it's worth, you have a list at [is_scalar()](https://www.php.net/is_scalar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But are compound types really objects?

Given the two compound types array and object (Cf. the two structures [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is built on), then in [PHP](https://php.net/) this is a clear *no*: array is array (array or associative array/hashmap) and *only* objects are really objects.

- https://php.net/array
- https://php.net/object

String is a scalar in the PHP nomenclature, not an array. There is no char type.

> [...] but in PHP, does something similar happen? [...] Do they inherit from Object?

For Array() (nowadays []) nothing inherits from object.

You can however create objects from classes that implement ArrayAccess, Countable and Traversable to create something array-like which then is an object.

```php
$object = new ArrayObject(['A']);
```

Still though, there is no single superclass, PHP has is_object() test, the instanceof operator, and [type declarations support for object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php).

There are also some interface+class hierarchies in the Standard PHP Library (SPL) and PHP core:

- [Predefined Exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php)

  - [SPL Exceptions Class Tree](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php#spl.exceptions.tree)
- [Predefined Interfaces and Classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php)

  - [Datastructures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php)
  - [Iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)
  - [Interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.interfaces.php)
- [Predefined Attributes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.attributes.php)

> Where can I find more information about this?

In the PHP manual in the [language reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) and in the [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php).

---

References:

- [Using properties of a class inside a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76747763/367456)

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question:

> But are compound types really objects?

Answer: Objects are one of the compound data types in PHP, but not all compound data types are objects. Each compound data type serves a specific purpose and is used to handle different kinds of data structures in PHP.

More details for beginners:
Scalar data types represent individual values, meaning they can only hold a single value at a time. PHP has four scalar data types:

```
$integerVar = 25;
$floatVar = 6.12;
$stringVar = "Do you know, PHP can go Native ?";
$booleanVar = false;
```

Compound data types can hold multiple values or a collection of values. PHP has two primary compound data types:

```
// Array
$colors = array("blue", "red", "green");

// Object (casting an array)
$colors = (object)array("blue", "red", "green");

// Object (using a simple stdClass object)
$person = new stdClass();
$person->name = "Adam";
$person->age = 90;

// Object (e.g., a database connection)
$dbConnection = new mysqli("localhost", "login", "password", "database");
echo $dbConnection->server_info, "\n";
```